# WinXP: Changing default double-click from Open to Explore?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Is it possible to configure XP so that a double-click on a folder opens up in Explorer view rather than the "regular" folder view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep!

1. Open any Explorer window
2. `Tools` -> `Folder Options` -> `File Types` tab
3. Find the entry for `(NONE) Folder` (*not* `(NONE) File Folder`)
4. Click `Advanced`
5. Select `explore`
6. Click `Set Default`
7. `OK`
8. `OK`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having local administrator access? My IT department locks things down pretty heavily